# Cancelling a request in Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, struts

I have a web application deployed in Tomcat 7 and one of the transactions there is loading a text file to the application then the application will read it line by line then insert all the records to the database.

I would like to put a cancel button on the page to let the users decide if they would like to cancel the transaction especially if they're uploading big files. I'm thinking to just put a link that goes to another page to serve as cancel button. Will this work?

Would the thread continue if the client uploads a 15MB file, which takes about 10 minutes to be processed, then decides to cancel it by clicking the link I provided as a cancel button?

Answer (score 1):

Once the file is uploaded to the server, start a thread to do the processing and store a reference to it somewhere (like a Hashtable) and give it a unique ID. Then render the page back to the user with the cancel button, and store the ID you used earlier to keep a reference to the thread in the page.

When the user clicks cancel, go back to the Hashtable, get the thread with the ID and send it a message to make it stop the import.

Of course, your method that will stop the thread from importing data will need to take into account current database transactions to be sure you dont leave your database in an invalid state.

Comment: so the thread won't cancel if the user just clicks on the link that I provide?

Comment: I think what @Jf Beaulac was implying was that you write an additional method (the cancel method) on the Servlet / Endpoint that takes an ID as it's parameter.  If the user calls that method, using the ID, you cancel the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to stop a request that is under transmission to the server. Once you click upload you make a HTTP request, and the process begins and clicking "cancel/link u provided" at a later point, would be a different HTTP request and since HTTP is stateless, it would not know anything what happened earlier or what to stop. So as expected it is not possible implicitly. But there may be something that can be done to do this which I am unaware of now. But if you press "esc" key that would terminate the request sent to the server. And since this is the only solution till now then on UI you can write this javascript code:

```
$('.your_link').click(function(){
        window.stop();
    });
```

window.stop() will not work on IE. for IE you can use:

```
document.execCommand("Stop");
```